Why do I run tensorflow code, and the GPU utilization is 0?
The CPU usage is high and the memory usage is high, but the GPU utilization is 0.
I ran the code： tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU');
The result is that my GPU information can be seen.
So what's the problem????
enter image description here
